# Glassdoor API - retrieve exact employerID

Tags: c#, json, api

I'm trying to retrieve reviews from specific employer with my glassdoor API credentials using C#.

I'm able to retrieve by company name, but then I don't get all the records for a specific company, I get only part of them. For example, if I pull UBS (e=UBS) I get exactly the matches of UBS, but on glassdoor you can see thousands of reviews for that employer.

If I use the parameter q=UBS, I tons of stuff totally unrelated.
Searching using employerId does not bring anything related either. 
Basically it seems that it pulls list of employers, but the documentation says it can pull reviews.
Any tips of what can be done? Glassdoor's API documentation is somewhat limited and unclear.
The API HttpWebRequest (one of the variations tried):

http://api.glassdoor.com/api/api.htm?v=1&format=json&t.p=GIVENBYGD&t.k=PASSWORD&action=employers&employerId=3149&userip=88.192.249.8&useragent=Mozilla/%2F4.0"

I fetched the employerId from results I got and noticed the parameter
(when queried e=UBS):

```
{
  "success": true,
  "status": "OK",
  "jsessionid": "83E368C30E814D6C85FDC84FBCF7C03A",
  "response": {
    "currentPageNumber": 1,
    "totalNumberOfPages": 2,
    "totalRecordCount": 14,
    "employers": [
      {
        "id": 3419,
        "name": "UBS",
        "website": "www.ubs.com",
        "isEEP": false,
        "exactMatch": true,
        "industry": "Investment Banking & Asset Management",
        "numberOfRatings": 1453,
        "squareLogo": "https://media.glassdoor.com/sqll/3419/ubs-squarelogo-1383039022554.png",
        "overallRating": 3.4,
        "ratingDescription": "OK",
        "cultureAndValuesRating": "0.0",
        "seniorLeadershipRating": "0.0",
        "compensationAndBenefitsRating": "0.0",
        "careerOpportunitiesRating": "0.0",
        "workLifeBalanceRating": "0.0",
        "recommendToFriendRating": "0.0",
        "ceo": {
          "name": "Sergio P. Ermotti",
          "title": "CEO",....
```

Anyone got a clue?

For example, i got UBS's employer's ID (3419) through the first request (when adding to the request e=UBS) but that's what I get from the request when employerId=3419.

#### This is a an example (json) for what I get when I use employerId=3419 (I cut off some parts to keep it short)

```
<code>
{
 "success": true, 
  "status": "OK",
  "jsessionid": "9F86EE2C0F50EF17FB50FF43B37D316F",
  "response": {
    "currentPageNumber": 1,
    "totalNumberOfPages": 31,
    "totalRecordCount": 305,
    "employers": [
      {
        "id": 3494,
        "name": "Nokia",
        "website": "LINK",
        "isEEP": false,
        "exactMatch": false,
        "industry": "Telecommunications Manufacturing",
        "numberOfRatings": 1430,
        "squareLogo": "LINK TO LOGO",
        "overallRating": 3.8,
        "ratingDescription": "Satisfied",
        "cultureAndValuesRating": "3.6",
        "seniorLeadershipRating": "2.4",
        "compensationAndBenefitsRating": "3.2",
        "careerOpportunitiesRating": "3.2",
        "workLifeBalanceRating": "3.8",
        "recommendToFriendRating": "0.6",
        "featuredReview": {
          "id": 5526822,
          "currentJob": false,
          "reviewDateTime": "2014-12-12 01:42:11.89",
          "jobTitle": "Employee",
          "location": "",
          "headline": "Sr. Engineering Manager",
          "pros": "Equal opportunity company, take good care of your well being and training.  Salary level is good. Ability to move also sideways on your career.",
          "cons": "Company works in very volatile market and market changes are frequent. You job location can change or disappear in short notice. Job security not as good as it used to be.",
          "overall": 4,
          "overallNumeric": 4
        },
        "ceo": {
          "name": "Rajeev Suri",
          "title": "CEO",
          "image": {
            "src": "LINK",
            "height": 50,
            "width": 40
          },
          "numberOfRatings": 90,
          "pctApprove": 53,
          "pctDisapprove": 47 
</code>
```

Comment: I know that this thread might be a little stale, but I've been creating some .NET SDKs for various web APIs including Glassdoor. I feel your pain as I cannot get their API to work the way I at least understand it. I either get nothing or too much and I agree that their documentation is vague at best. I've reached out to them recently, but haven't heard from them yet. Feel free to contact me if you're interested in seeing the SDK. It's not ready for prime time yet.

Comment: @DanielPrzybylski is it ready now?  :P

Comment: @DanielPrzybylski is it ready now? I'm really interested in it

Comment: See: http://janglin.com/Glassdoor & https://www.nuget.org/packages/JanglinGlassDoorApiSdk . Contact me thru those resources for more help/issues. Thank you.